# Answer abaqus overwrite prompts programmatically

Tags: batch-file, abaqus

When I run

```
call abaqus job=some_name interactive
```

two things might happen:

1. If it is the first time I run the job, no inquiries are made.
2. if, however, the job exists, I get this message:

   ```
    Old job exist. Overwrite? (y/n):
   ```

I want my script to always respond with

```
 y
```

I have tried

```
 /Q and echo n|call
```

without luck.

Answer (score 10):

Add `ask_delete=OFF` to the end of the job execution command.

```
abaqus job=some_name interactive ask_delete=OFF
```

Comment: you can also put `ask_delete=OFF` in your abaqus_v6.env file

Answer (score 2):

For abaqus what you really should do rather than building a batch file, is to build a python execution script that imports and runs the code.

Documentation for the Python API is in the abaqus scripting manual but the code would look something like this:

```py
# yourscript.py
for filepath in list of filepaths:
  mdb.JobFromInputFile(name='filename', inputFileName='filepath',)
  mdb.jobs['filename'].submit()
  mdb.waitForCompletion()
```

Then submit with the command

```bash
>>> abaqus python yourscript.py
```

This will overwrite what you already have. If you really want to get fancy, you can use python to open the `*.dat` or `*.msg` files associated with your run in your working directory, and look at the last line of text and see if the existing files correspond to successful runs or not, too.

This also opens up the world of python to you and lets you do lots more than just submitting files.

Answer (score -1):

In a batch file, Delete the old job before launching the program.

Comment: I would rather find a more elegant solution if possible